# How can I exclude users in a survey with the same ID for calculations in R?

Tags: r

My data.frame includes the results from a survey and looks like this:

| date | id | age | gender | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-02 | 99 | 20 | 1 | ... |
| 01-20 | 52 | 34 | 2 | ... |
| 01-23 | 47 | 20 | 1 | ... |
| 01-02 | 100 | 56 | 1 | ... |
| 02-05 | 99 | 20 | 1 | ... |
| 02-17 | 78 | 18 | 2 | ... |
| 02-28 | 47 | 20 | 1 | ... |

the users are allowed to attend each month, up to 10 times at the survey, so I have users who's personal data occurs more often in the table.

Now to my problem:
How can I get the mean (e.g. age) of all users who attended the survey? If I just put it mean(df$age), obviously those who did attend more than once will be overrepresented.

How can I get a list with counting users who attended once, twice, ... ten times?
e.g.:

| number of participations | number of users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,047 |
| 2 | 23,127 |
| 3 | 50,000 |

I haven't found a solution for this, so I'm grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: first question obviously should be: how to insert tables in my questions...

Comment: To make reproducible examples just use `dput(your_df)` and paste the output in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get average age of the participants you can keep only the unique `id`'s of the data and calculate the average.

In `dplyr` you can do this with `distinct` and `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(avg_age = mean(age))

#  avg_age
#1    29.6
```

To count how many times an individual responded to the survey you can use `count`

```
df %>% count(id, name = 'count')

#   id count
#1  47     2
#2  52     1
#3  78     1
#4  99     2
#5 100     1
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("01-02", "01-20", "01-23", "01-02", "02-05", 
"02-17", "02-28"), id = c(99L, 52L, 47L, 100L, 99L, 78L, 47L), 
    age = c(20L, 34L, 20L, 56L, 20L, 18L, 20L), gender = c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Unfortunately, it's still not working. Regarding issue 1: What R provides me, is a list with the ids and the age corresponding to each id. Regarding issue 2: What I wanted was not the number of attendances for each user but instead  how many people attended once, twice, etc. So the table should look like 
#1    1     2,345
#2    2     1,902
#3    3     1,807
#4    4     2,001
#5    5     14,234
#6    6     2,002
#7    7     120,000
#8    8     17,823
#9    9     2,345
#10 10    1,765       so the last line tells me 1,765 users attended 10 times, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example as I have shared in my answer and show the exact expected output for that data so that it is clear what are you looking for.

Comment: Actually your first example worked. I had a group_by(id) hidden in my code. Many Thanks for the help here!

Comment: For the 2nd question my example-df is the following:
id <- c(99, 52, 47, 100, 99, 78, 47)
date <- c("2020-01-02", "2020-01-20", "2020-01-23", "2020-01-02", "2020-02-05", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-28")
age <- c(20, 34, 21, 56, 20, 18, 21)
gender <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)
answer <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(id, date, age, gender, answer)
the result should look as the following:
attend <- cbind(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), c(3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
colnames(attend) <- (c("number of participations", "number of interviewees"))
attend.

Comment: @Heiko Your 2nd question can be answered by `df %>% count(id, name = 'count') %>% count(count)`